# Parse number to exact 2 decimal place with output type as number or float in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to parse a number in JavaScript to exact 2 decimals for all kinds of input values.
for Eg.

```
input = 631, required output = 631.00, type = float
input = 631.3, required output = 631.30, type = float
input = 631.333, required output = 631.33, type = float
```

I tried as below options

```
input = 631  
output = parseFloat(input).toFixed(2) // '631.00'
```

here type is coming as a string, which is not required.

```
input = 631.3  
output = parseFloat(input) // 631.3
```

I want it to be exact 2 decimals

I also tried `num.toPrecision(totalDigits)`, but it requires total digits to be required.

API call

```
curl -X POST \
  https://www.wepay.in.th/client_api.php \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
  -H 'content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
  -d 'username=xxxxx&password=xxxxxx&json=true&resp_url=https%3A%2F%2Fapi.witpay.co.th%2Fproccesswepay&pay_to_ref3=&pay_to_barcode1=&type=mtopup&pay_to_company=12CALL&pay_to_ref2=&pay_to_ref1=0929418926&dest_ref=34&pay_to_amount=10.00'
```

API call in nodeJS

```
const params = {
  dest_ref: client_ref,
  pay_to_company: serviceCode,
  pay_to_amount: parseFloat(amount).toFixed(2),
  pay_to_ref1: payToRef1,
}

request({
  baseUrl,
  url: '/client_api.php', // URL to hit
  method: 'POST',
  form: params,
  headers: [{
    name: 'content-type',
    value: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
  }],
}, (error, response, body) => {
  // handle response and error
})
```

PS: This is format it required from 3rd party API, so can't change it.

Comment: where do you want to use it since 631.3 == 631.30

Comment: Using a string for that is the only possible way. Floats only have necessary decimals (i.e. no zeros at the end) and integers do not have decimals at all.

Comment: I'm making a API call to 3rd party, where if I say amount equals to 631.3 or '631.30', it is getting failed with error message to be exact `631.30`.

Comment: If I tried putting manually like 631.30, then It is getting success.

Comment: Please provide examples of the exact calls you make to the API. Including one that works, and one that does not.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking, if you want exactly 2 decimals in all cases you **must** use a string.

Comment: floating point numbers do not have a "number of decimal places" - that is solely a display thing. Also, integers do not have *any* decimal places. They are integers. What is your actual question? That an external API is not working? If so ask the vendor - they are the only people who can really help you.

Comment: please add the api call.

Comment: API are with 3rd party credentials, I've no control over them.

Comment: How the question is unclear? I wanted to send a value with 2 decimal place, without string???

Comment: The requirement if not using a string is wrong. You send your number as a query string which *is* a string by definition. So you can send the response of `toFixed` to the API (without the quotes of course) and it will work.

Comment: Its not query string, its url encodes post request, 
if value is going in between quotes, '631.30', as putting it from variable, it failed, if without quotes, getting success.

Comment: It does not matter, it is still a string. And as I already wrote, do *not* add quotes around the number.

Comment: I'm not added any quotes, If put the value from variable after converting, it is getting added automatically.

Comment: Then how do you add it? Please edit your question and add your code. You are making it very hard to help.

Comment: Do you not see that your form post data **is a string**. So you just use `toFixed(2)` when building that string.

Comment: yes it is, but when value is assigned it should only be number format. which is making it, failed.

Answer (score 0):

**parseFloat(input).toFixed(2)** is the perfect approach and you will always get the data type of the floating point numbers as a **string** because javascript only supports the below mentioned primitive data types:

1. Boolean
2. Null
3. Undefined
4. Number
5. String
6. Symbol (new in ECMAScript 6)

Floating point numbers can be represented as a **number** type but as you said they will not be of any use because when you try to convert them to numbers it will give you the same response as given by **parseFloat**.